# In Python, efficiently determine if two lists are shifted copies of one another

Tags: python, list, compare

What's the most efficient (in time) way of checking if two relatively short (about 3-8 elements) lists are shifted copies of one another?  And if so, determine and return the offset?

Here is the example code and output I'd like:

```
>>> def is_shifted_copy(list_one, list_two):
>>>     # TODO
>>>
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
0
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])
2
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])
None
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1])
None
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1])
1
```

Lists may have duplicate entries.  If more than one offset is valid, return any offset.

Comment: if the lists are shorts, why caring about time efficiency!

Comment: Yeah, if speed is that important, you should use an alternative data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching two copies of the first list allows us to avoid performing excessive concatenation:

```
def is_shifted_copy(l1, l2):
    l1l1 = l1 * 2
    n = len(l1)
    return next((i for i in range(n) if l1l1[i:i + n] == l2), None)
```

Comment: 3 lines, no try statements, performance very close to the best of the other solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: note: it is `O(n**2)` time, `O(n)` space. If `n` is large; [@thkang solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15415525/4279) that is O(n) time, O(1) space might be preferable. Though for `n ~ 3..8` it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

here's a simple iterator version that does the job in 2n iterations (n being the length of list)

```
import itertools

def is_shifted_copy(list1, list2):

    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False

    iterator = iter(list2)

    for i, item in enumerate(itertools.chain(list1, list1)):
        try:
            if item == iterator.next():
                continue
            else:
                iterator = iter(list2)
        except StopIteration:
            return i - len(list2)

    else:
        return False


print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]) #0
print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]) #2
print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]) #False
print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]) #1
print is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1]) #2
print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1]) #False
print is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]) #1
print is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]) #0
```

and from your specification,

shouldn't `is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1])` return `2`?

Comment: I think the spec is consistent.  But that's a detail.  I don't really care if you return 1 or 2, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: `is_shifted_copy([0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0])` produce a wrong answer of `False`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution based on indexes and slicing:

```
>>> def is_shifted_copy(l1, l2):
    try:
        return [l1[-i:] + l1[:-i] for i in range(len(l1))].index(l2)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

The result is as expected:

```
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
0
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])
2
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])
None
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is a modified version of NPE's solution, which checks for all possible match positions. It compares favorably to thkang's (and ecatmur's) clever iterator solutions:

```
import itertools as IT

def is_shifted_copy_thkang(list1, list2):
    N = len(list1)
    if N != len(list2):
        return None
    elif N == 0:
        return 0
    next_item = iter(list2).next
    for i, item in enumerate(IT.chain(list1, list1)):
        try:
            if item == next_item():
                continue
            else:
                next_item = iter(list2).next
        except StopIteration:
            return -i % N
    else:
        return None

def is_shifted_copy_NPE(list1, list2):
    N = len(list1)
    if N != len(list2):
        return None
    elif N == 0:
        return 0

    pos = -1
    first = list1[0]
    while pos < N:
        try:
            pos = list2.index(first, pos+1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        if (list2 + list2)[pos:pos+N] == list1:
            return pos
    return None

def is_shifted_copy_ecatmur(l1, l2):
    l1l1 = l1 * 2
    n = len(l1)
    return next((-i % n for i in range(n) if l1l1[i:i + n] == l2), None)


tests = [
    # ([], [], 0),    
    ([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 0),
    ([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], 1),
    ([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], 2),
    ([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], None),
    ([1, 2, 3], [1], None),
    ([1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1], 1),
    ([1,2,3,1,3,2], [1,3,2,1,2,3], 3)
    ]

for list1, list2, answer in tests:
    print(list1, list2, answer)
    assert is_shifted_copy_thkang(list1, list2) == answer
    assert is_shifted_copy_NPE(list1, list2) == answer    
    assert is_shifted_copy_ecatmur(list1, list2) == answer
```

---

```
In [378]: %timeit is_shifted_copy_thkang([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.5 us per loop

In [377]: %timeit is_shifted_copy_ecatmur([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.37 us per loop

In [379]: %timeit is_shifted_copy_NPE([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 us per loop
```

---

Note: I changed the return value in `is_shifted_copy_thkang` and `is_shifted_copy_ecatmur` so that all three versions would pass the tests in the original post.

I benchmarked the functions with and without the change and found it  does not significantly affect the performance of the functions.

For example, with `return i`:

```
In [384]: %timeit is_shifted_copy_thkang([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.38 us per loop
```

With `return -i % N`:

```
In [378]: %timeit is_shifted_copy_thkang([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.5 us per loop
```

Comment: why `i % n` if `i in range(n)`? Mere `i` should be enough.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for spotting the error. I had intended it to be `-i % n for i in range(n)...` (so all versions would pass the same tests) but somehow got a typo.

Comment: you could use `next_item = iter(list2).next` in @thkang's version. Shouldn't it return `0` in the `else` clause (empty lists case)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I changed thkang's to use `next_item = iter(list2).next` since that improves the speed a bit. I fixed the thkang and NPE versions to return 0 when fed two empty lists, but I don't see a beautiful way to change ecatmur's code which is so pithy I don't want to touch it. The timings stay about the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Flawed solution**

Unfortunately, the solution by thkang and the modified version from unutbu fail for surprisingly simple inputs.

For example, we (correctly) get an integer result for the lists `[1, 2, 1]` and `[1, 1, 2]`:

```
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2])
2
```

However, when swapping the arguments, we get the (incorrect) result `False`:

```
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1])
False
```

Similarly, other lists that are shifted copies aren't treated correctly:

```
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2])
False
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1])
False
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 1, 3, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
False
```

To understand the source of this problem, let me reproduce the current version of thkang's solution (with a modified call to `next` for Python 3):

```
import itertools

def is_shifted_copy(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False

    iterator = iter(list2)

    for i, item in enumerate(itertools.chain(list1, list1)):
        try:
            if item == next(iterator):
                continue
            else:
                iterator = iter(list2)  # Reset iterator
        except StopIteration:
            return i - len(list2)
    else:
        return False
```

Now, the following happens for a call like `is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2])`:

| i | item | next(iterator) | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2^ | reset iterator |
| 1 | 2 | 2^ | continue |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | reset iterator |
| 3 | 1 | 2^ | reset iterator |
| 4 | 2 | 2^ | continue |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | reset iterator, return False |

^ First element of `list2`.

As we can see, the repeated elements in the input lists cause the iterator `itertools.chain(list1, list1)` to be exhausted before we even have the chance to get to the final element of `list2`.

**Possible fix**

If we insist on using iterators (to prevent copying of potentially large input lists, for example), we'd have to ensure the iterator for the first list isn't exhausted before we can make a comparison with the elements from the second list. The only approach I can currently think of that guarantees a non-exhausted first iterator is creating a new iterator for all possible shifted versions of `list1`:

```
import itertools

def is_shifted_copy(list1, list2):
    length = len(list1)

    if len(list2) != length:
        return

    for i in range(length):
        iterator1 = itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(list1), i, i + length + 1)
        iterator2 = iter(list2)

        for item in iterator1:
            try:
                if item != next(iterator2):
                    break
            except StopIteration:
                return -i % length

    return None
```

```
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
0
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])
2
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1])
None
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 3], [1])
None
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1])
2
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2])
1
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1])
3
>>> is_shifted_copy([1, 2, 1, 3, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
1
```

At best, the above algorithm finishes in `O(n)` steps. The algorithm performs worst, namely `O(n^2)` in time, for input lists with mostly duplicate elements.